# InvalidPathException on passing git url in code

Tags: java, file

I am getting java.nio.file.InvalidPathException on passing a url in my code. I have tried forward and backward slashes but still getting the same error.
Code-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Ref;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository;
import org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileRepositoryBuilder;

public class testInAction 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
String repoUrl = "http://stash.gto.intranet.db.com:8081/projects/PARAGON/repos/paragongit/browse";
Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(new File(repoUrl)).readEnvironment().findGitDir().build();
listRepositoryContents(repository);
        repository.close();
    }

private static void listRepositoryContents(Repository repository) throws IOException {
        for (Ref head : repository.getAllRefs().values()) {
            String refName = head.getName();
            ObjectId objId = head.getObjectId();
            System.out.println("refName " + refName);
            System.out.println("objId " + objId);
        }
    }
}
```

what can be the reason for this...suggest some

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, the input to `setGitDir` should be a relative or absolute path to your *local* Git repository, not the remote one.  So, it makes no sense to be using a remote URL there, nor does it make any sense to be calling `File(...)` with a URL.  Try something along these lines:

```
FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
String gitPath = "\path\to\your\git\folder";
Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(new File(gitPath))
    .readEnvironment().findGitDir().build();
listRepositoryContents(repository);
repository.close();
```

Comment: ok...but I want to pass a remote url here, so how can it be done?